# Running a GDB LINUX COMMAND THROUGH JAVA

Tags: java, linux, sockets, gdb

I tried to run `String command ="gdb -p <124845> --batch -ex 'call shutdown(69u)'"` or close() instead of shutdown(). Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

COMMAND GETS EXECUTED BUT HAS NO EFFECT ,

But when run in putty then it works fine.

PLEASE help ,i'm new to this.

My goal is to clear all connections to a java socket in linux machine.

Comment: You should specify pid number without angle brackets like this `-p 124845`. The command with angle brackets should not work fine when it run in putty also.

Comment: Im using without angle bracket only, i just showed that way, query is running as well from java but its not closing the connection

Comment: The .exec is breaking up the command into tokens but doesn't understand what single quotes mean, so it's running the command with the argument list `["gdb", "-p", "124845", "--batch", "-ex", "'call", "shutdown(69u)'"]`. Can you see if the following answers your question?  [Java execute command doesn't work in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900007/2554472)

Comment: Thanks ill try this also, but even earlier it was returning the same response in process.inpustream as it returns in command prompt but it was not actually closing the connection, ill check of this works ty

Comment: The gdb --batch option will return exit code 0 in many cases, even if accompanied by -ex options that fail. `gdb --batch -ex UnknownCommand` returns 0.

Comment: Yes, true its returning zero in some cases but connection not closing